# f_open not creating file?

Tags: php, file, social-networking

I am starting a social network that uses Windows Notepad files to save the "feed" of the person. But, on my account saving page, my PHP does not seem to work. It will not save the file. Sorry if I am a "noob"

Here be my code:

```
<?php
$u = $_POST['user'];
$n = $_POST['name'];
$p = $_POST['password'];
$e = $_POST['email'];
$f = $_POST['email'] . ".txt";

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","account");
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO socialnet (name,user,password,file,email) VALUES ($n,$u,$p,$f,$e)");

$o = fopen('/' . $f,'c');

fwrite($o,"Hi. I just joined. Wait a few until I get my feed going");
fclose($o);
echo "<b>Your account has been saved. Now, please click the link at the top of the page to go back and log in.</b>";

?>
```

Please, no harsh responses.

Comment: Do you have write permissions inside the target folder? You have to set folders permissions to 777 and there are serveral ways to do this depend on the way you have access to that folder. via shell it is chmod 777 /foldername/

Comment: Yes. Its my own server

Comment: Please fix the SQL injection holes! Use prepared statements.

Comment: You realise you're actually trying to create the file in the filesystem root directory?

Comment: fopen() and fwrite() have failure condition, you need to check the value they return for error, same goes for mysqli_query and any function you will ever use. If if can fail, you have to check if it did or not.

Comment: So your saying that I am saving it to C:/?

Comment: Ok you're running windows thats different I'm out

Comment: Try saving it to the database instead of a file.  File I/O on a web page can have many concurrency issues.

Comment: /filename.txt is the equivalent of C:\filename.txt

Comment: I cannot save it to the database. Even though it may take less space, I want quite large posts to occur and the only thing I know to do in MYSQLI is the query.Besides that it is PHP MYADMIN, which currently doesn't have an infinite setting

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to write files to the root directory of the server (`/`). Pick or create a directory that you *do* have write privileges on, and use that instead.

Comment: @ANGRYANDY: Are you using shared hosting?

Comment: @Igancio_Vazqez-Abrams: No. I am using my own WAMP server. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @ANGRYANDY: Yes. It means that you need to create the directory and give it the appropriate permissions for the web server to write to it yourself.

Comment: @Igancia_Vazquez-Abrams: So, How do I do that on a windows computer running Wamp? Do I change the config files?

Comment: @ANGRYANDY: There should be a permissions tab on the properties page of the folder you create. Give the user the web server runs as read and write permissions.